# Google Webfonts not working with Zurb Foundation on Android Browser

Tags: zurb-foundation, android-browser, google-webfonts

I have got the following issue. I'm using a google webfont in a project i did with Foundation. The thing is, it is working on any browser but not on the Android Browser on a Samsung Galaxy Note. The Android Browser is showing a standard font.

For testing purpose i tried it with a simple html file to check if it's a general problem with google fonts. But it was working. Then i tried a clean Foundation-Installation, I added the google font and changed all font-family tags. And again, the same result. It is working on FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, but not on the Android Browser.

The installed System is Android 4.2.2

Zurb Foundation Head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```

CSS-changes in foundation.css

```
font-family: 'Exo 2','sans-serif';
```

I changed every font-family line like above.

Result in Adroid Browser:

http://uploadpie.com/lec8E

Result in Chrome:

http://uploadpie.com/qt3qK

I hope you guys have any ideas or solutions. Thanx for your help.

Cheers
Tom

Comment: please post your code so people can help you with root cause and solution

Comment: both of your UploadPie links are redirecting to the home page, I'm assuming that these files have been deleted since you've fixed this issue? If this is the case please close your question and post your fix below as an answer.